# UWP: GetFileAsync on a partial path?

Tags: c#, file, uwp, window, win-universal-app

I'm trying to get a single file in an UWP based on its partial name. Basically, I want to select a file that starts with "latest_" in a given folder.
Right now I can do that with that command:

```cs
var previousInfo = (await rootFolder.GetFilesAsync()).Where(file => file.DisplayName.StartsWith("latest_")).FirstOrDefault();
```

I suppose this code is not very efficient if there are a lot of files in the folder...
Is there a simpler way to do this? Like:

```cs
var previousInfo2 = await rootFolder.GetFileAsync("latest_*");
```

Or:

```
var previousInfo2 = await rootFolder.GetFileAsync(@"latest_*");
```

Right now this code is throwing an exception (invalid parameter). And the MSDN documentation about this function is very light: it just says that the function takes a string as parameter...
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by using [Advanced Query Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266512(v=vs.85).aspx) and in fact, you can filter/search by many more file metadata. Below is an example for search based on File Name.

```
var queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
queryOptions.ApplicationSearchFilter = "System.FileName:latest_*";

StorageFileQueryResult queryResult = rootFolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);

var files = await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();
```

Comment: Neat! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!